# Do we need a "marlin-2.0" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently a question got tagged with the [marlin-2.0](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marlin-2.0) tag which I changed to [marlin](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marlin).

Should we allow a new tag for Marlin 2.0 since this firmware branch is significantly different from version 1.1.x?

Answer (score 2):

I'm inclined to not add the [marlin-2.0](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marlin-2.0) tag, else we have to create a new tag for every version that may come. From the question it should be made clear for which version the problem arises.

Also, some supposedly Marlin 2.0 problems may be just old legacy code problems.